# how to keep two separate working directories in sync -- or is git able to recognize identical commits?

Tags: git

1. (in some working directory A) I did some local changes and performed add and commit
2. (in some working directory B) I got a patch for these local changes (in directory A) and applied it in directory B. I performed add/commit/push in directory B.
3. (in the working directory A) I performed a git pull and expected my local commit to disappear. It did not.
4. (in the working directory A) I performed a git reset HEAD~. git diff shows the changes which are already pushed earlier. (**forget about this point** -- this was my attempt to solve this problem)

Obviously I did something wrong. what is it?

Comment: You mention working directories, but what about the underlying Git directory or directories? Are you using `git worktree add` to create the additional working directories?

Comment: the directories are on different machines

Comment: Ah, OK, that clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you described:
On machine 1 make commit X
On machine 2 apply a patch which does the same thing, and create commit X'
Push commit X'

On machine 1 pull commit X'
Machine 1 now has 2 commits:  X and X'

You reset HEAD~ on machine 1, removing commit X', and leaving commit X.

The pull is a fetch followed by a merge.My understanding is that in a merge git can recognize identical changes.

Still, it might be interesting to do the pull again, and run
git show HEAD
to see what was committed.
Perhaps it's a merge commit with very little content?
Someone with more plumbing knowledge could answer that better that I can.
It is likely to depend on what you merge settings are also.  Merge, rebase?

Comment: I understood your answer until/including "you reset". Then I'm lost. Are you suggesting I should have performed a git merge?

Comment: what I meant to imply is that I expected the duplicate commit to be ignored because the content is already there. The experiment is proposed was to run git show HEAD,  do the pull again, and run git show HEAD again, to see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* ways to look at how you might coordinate the content across two machines' working directories.

The most basic is: if you committed changes on machine A, and want them on machine B, you can fetch them from A to B so that A and B will have the patch *via the same commit*.  Sometimes that's not a suitable answer, and so other ways are possible.  But which one makes sense for what you're doing depends on what you're doing, and we don't know enough to necessarily address that yet.

So we can follow up on that if it makes sense, but let's start by clarifying a possible conceptual misunderstanding:

> (in the working directory A) I performed a git pull and expected my local commit to disappear. It did not.

My question would be, why is that the expected behavior?  In general, you don't *want* your local changes to disappear when you pull in remote changes; instead you want to combine them.

Now, in the specific case where the local changes and the remote changes are identical, you *might* indeed want the local changes to go away, and if you rebase the local changes onto the newly-fetched remote changes then that is what should happen.

```
git pull --rebase
```

Now if, in the process of rebasing your local changes onto the fetched changes, git finds that a local commit's patch is *exactly* the same as the patch for one of the fetched commits, the local commit will be discarded.

Perhaps you expected that behavior because in the past you've used repos configured to rebase on pull by default?  Be aware that auto-rebasing is documented as a "potentially dangerous" feature, so you might want to consider if it's really the best default; but if it is the default you want, look up `pull.rebase` in the git config docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: are you saying the answer is the parameter --rebase for git pull?

Comment: yes -- I expected this to be merged automatically. One reason for this is, that I cannot imagine multiple unnamed tips of a source code control system. And I was told, that --rebase is only cosmetic to reorder local commits to come after remote commits. The basic problem is, that git is basically undocumented (and also bad designed).

Comment: from the man page:
"More precisely, git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and calls git merge to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch. With --rebase, it runs git rebase instead of git
       merge."

Comment: @FrankPuck - Ok... taking those one at a time.  First: No, I am not saying that "the answer" is the parameter --rebase; if I were saying that's the answer, my answer would be quite a lot shorter.

Comment: @FrankPuck - Expecting pull to merge automatically - which it does - is not the same as expecting the commit you made to be gone - which would only happen under specific conditions, including that you use the `--rebase` option.  git is neither undocumented in this behavior, nor poorly designed.

Comment: @FrankPuck - as for your last comment... yes, I'm aware.  That's the point I was making above.  Because a merge will NOT delete the local commit, as you claim to expect should've happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a git pull, but I would use rsync

```
cd directory_A; rsync -mauvPAX directory_B/ .
```

This would efficiently duplicate the content of directory_B into directory_A and preserve any files in directory_A that are missing from directory_B.

If you want to scrub any additional files from directory_A that aren't in directory_B then include the `--delete` flag.